# How to setup a Partner dev org?

Tags: partner-portal, org

I am enrolled as in the Partner program. How do I create a Partner dev org ?

I know how to sign up for a normal dev org but unsure of setting up a Partner dev org.

Also, how do I tell whether my org is: a dev org OR a Partner dev org ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It used to be that you created these orgs via the partner portal, but the partner portal was retired a year or so back. It was replaced with the partner **community** which is what you have access to now.

However you don't create orgs from the partner community, rather you use the **Environment Hu**b tab in your partner business org. If you don't have one yet open a case on the partner community and they should give you an enterprise edition org with two licenses for you to use for production use (i.e. run your sales and service). This org will also have some ISV tools installed for you, including the license management app and the environment hub (which in turn can create test and dev orgs for you on demand).